# Should I use a has_and_belongs_to_many relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relation

I'm trying to implement sponsored photos, so I have my photos table and my sponsors table.

Sponsor will have many photos, and photos will have many sponsors.

Should I use a **has_and_belongs_to_many** relation in both of the models?

In that case,

1.) Should I create a join intermediate table manually or Rails will do It automatically?

2.) Should I add `photo_id` to `sponsors` and `sponsor_id` to `photos` ?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this case,[The has_many :through Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) will work great

```
sponsor.rb    
 has_many :sponsor_photos, :dependent => :destroy
 has_many :photos, :through => :sponsor_photos


photo.rb
has_many :sponsor_photos, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :sponsors, :through => :sponsor_photos

sponsor_photo.rb
##holding only sponsor_id and photo_id
  belongs_to :sponsor
  belongs_to :photo


###########so now you can use################

@sponsor=Sponsor.first
##get all photos of a  sponsor
@sponsor.photos
@photo=Photo.first
##get all sponsors from a photo
@photo.sponsors
```

HOPE THIS HELPS...

Comment: You can refer guides.rubyonrails.org/ in case you are stuck in future.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you'll benefit from `has_and_belongs_to_many` - if you don't want to include any specific information in the join table. I'll give you information on `has_many :through` to give you an overview of both approaches

---

[**HABTM**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)

`has_and_belongs_to_many` is used if you just want to associate two tables.

It's "dumb" in that it doesn't rely on [`primary keys`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key) - only housing two [`foreign_key`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) columns in the data-table. It's for this reason that you cannot include any specific information in the join model:

[image]

This means that if you want to use `has_and_belongs_to_many`, you'll be able to do this:

```
#app/models/sponsor.rb
class Sponsors < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :photos
end

#app/models/photo.rb
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :sponsors
end
```

You'll then need to create a join table, with the name `[plural_alphabetical_model]_[plural_alphabetical_model]`

> $ rails g migration CreatePhotosSponsors

```
#db/migrate/create_photos_sponsors.rb
class CreatePhotosSponsors < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :photo_sponsors, :id => false do |t|
        t.references :photo
        t.references :sponsor
    end
    add_index :photos_sponsors, [:photo_id, :sponsor_id]
    add_index :photos_sponsors, :sponsor_id
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :photos_students
  end
end
```

---

[**has_many :through**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

An alternative to the HABTM method is the `has_many :through` association. If you wanted to add specific information to your join data, you'll want to use this association. Reason being that it has a `primary_key` in the data table (and so can reference individual records):

[image]

```
#app/models/student.rb
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :sponsor_photos
   has_many :photos, through: :sponsor_photos
end

#app/models/sponsor_photo.rb
class SponsorPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :sponsor
   belongs_to :photo
end

#app/models/photo.rb
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :sponsor_photos
   has_many :sponsors, through: :sponsor_photos
end
```

The beauty of this association is that you can include specific information in the join model, such as the price paid, or their expiry date

Comment: Perfectly answered. Understood, I will use the through option, so I can put some custom attributes into the join table. Thanks Rich

Answer (score 2):

First the habtm relation, quoting from 'rails 4 way'

> **7.5.1 has_and_belongs_to_many**
>   Before proceeding with this section, I must clear my conscience by stating that **has_and_belongs_to_many** is practically obsolete in the minds of many Rails developers, including the authors of this book. Use **has_many :through** instead and your life should be a lot easier.

generate a joining model SponsorPhoto for example, with `photo_id` and `sponsor_id`

```
class Sponsor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos, through: :sponsor_photos
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has many :sponsors, through :sponsor_photos
end

class SponsorPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sponsors
  belongs_to :photos
end
```